# Django problem with missing " underscore" in url

Tags: python, django, url

I am a beginner and need a little support.
Everything works in the application, but when in the form it typing "new york", "_" is missing in the url.

My code is

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.POST['city']
   
        if city == '':
            return redirect('index')
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=1b79ea7b1251b76ccda81d6bd').read()
       

        json_data = json.loads(res)
        datas = {
            "country_code" : str(json_data['sys']['country']),
            "cordinate": str(json_data['coord']['lon'])+ ''+ 
            str(json_data['coord']['lat']),
            "temp": str(int(json_data['main']['temp']-273)) + 'C',
            "pressure" : str(json_data['main']['pressure']),
            "humidity" : str(json_data['main']['humidity']),

        }
```

In response receives "

```
InvalidURL at /
URL can't contain control characters. '/data/2.5/weather?q=bielsko biala&appid=1b79ea7b1251b76cc0b41a81d6bd' (found at least ' ')
```

I am looking for solutions on the Internet but I cannot solve it myself. Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: lets Try new+york?

Comment: there is a typo in your code, res = res = urllib...

Comment: I have already corrected thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to replace spaces in city with the encoded values.

Try this:

```
import urllib.parse    
res = urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={urllib.parse.quote(city)}&appid=1b79ea7b1251b76ccda81d6bd').read()
```

this is to encode city in the URL.

Comment: then gets this:
TypeError at /
can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

Comment: can you edit your code to print value and the type of city?

Comment: your advice with replace. When I type berlin everything works, but when I type new york it gets HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: I just checked it is because it is invalid URL, open weather API doesn't have _ in city names, you have to encode spaces to %20 for it to work

Comment: @Tomekr I have updated my answer, it should work now.